# Symbol.iterator на TypeScript

Tags: typescript, итераторы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно описать на TypeScript метод `next` объекта, который возвращается в `Symbol.iterator`.

За основу своего кода я взял пример описания простого перебираемого объекта на чистом JS из учебника.

```
interface Range extends Iterable<number> {
    from: number;
    to: number;
}

const range: Range = {
    from: 1,
    to: 5,
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        interface RangeIterator extends Iterator<number> {
            current: number;
            last: number;
            // next: () => { done: boolean; value?: number; }
            // так я написал сначала
            
            next: (...args: [] | [undefined]) => IteratorResult<number, any>;
            // так требует указать компилятор TS
        }

        const rangeIterator: RangeIterator = {
            current: this.from,
            last: this.to,

            // @ts-ignore
            // здесь естественно возникает ошибка, т.к. в аргументах next нет никаких ...args: [] | [undefined]

            next() {
                if (this.current <= this.last) {
                    return { done: false, value: this.current++ };
                } else {
                    return { done: true };
                }
            },
        }
        return rangeIterator;
    }
};
```

Comment: _здесь естественно возникает ошибка, т.к. в аргументах next нет никаких `...args: [] | [undefined]`_ - ошибка возникает не из-за аргументов. В тексте ошибки указано, что именно не хватает

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за комментарий, вы можете подсказать, как корректно исправить ошибку?

Comment: изменить возвращаемый тип: any -> undefined

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, это связано с тем, что next в одном случае возвращает объект с `value`, а в другом - нет?

Comment: немного сложнее, но да.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @Grundy за то, что помог разобраться. Пока разбирался с этой темой, решил у себя ещё один похожий вопрос. Не знаю, насколько это верное решение, но по крайней мере TS не ругается и не пришлось нигде указывать `any`.

```
interface ListIterator<T> extends Iterator<T> {
    current: ListNode<T> | null;
    next: (...args: [] | [undefined]) => IteratorResult<T, undefined>;
}


[Symbol.iterator](): ListIterator<T> {
    const listIterator: ListIterator<T> = {
        current: this.#head,
        next() {
            if (this.current !== null) {
                const { value, next } = this.current;
                this.current = next;
                return { done: false, value: value };
             } else {
                return { done: true, value: undefined };
             }
        }
    }
    return listIterator;
}
```

Ключевой момент `{ done: true, value: undefined }`.
Пока я не добавил в `{ done: true }` `value: undefined`, не заработало.